# Issue adding dynamic link in email template - CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I have a process which triggers when a case is assign, the process send an email to the case owner with the content of the case which also include a dynamic link to the case assigned. I could achieve it in CRM 2011 however I don't see any option to insert dynamic link in CRM 365. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using template in workflow does not have this hyperlink option, but direct Email message will have.

Refer [this community discussion](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/164038/how-to-add-record-url-dynamic-to-email-template-on-crm-2015) for the different implementation ideas.

> Dynamics CRM OOB does not support adding Record URL (Dynamic) to email template!
>
> There is workaround, by adding a new custom field to the case entity, then create a workflow to fire on case create which updates the new field to be a Record URL (Dynamic), then simply add this field to your email template and attach the email template to your workflow

Comment: Still? Unfortunate because it seems very intuitive that if Workflow Send Email has it... why wouldn't Email Template? Very "surprising". Further, the workaround is not good if you're building on premise and then using FastTrack to migrate to the cloud... the URL's will be wrong since the record is now in a different CRM org with a different URL in the cloud.